# :app:processDebugResources Error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, windows

Not quite sure why I keep getting this error:
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHkWX.png)

After some searching, it seems like the issue is in my build.gradle file but I cannot find it. I've attached the file, but also include the screenshot of my errors in case there is something I am missing. 
but that did not changed anything.

**Build.gradle** file below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cormac.splashscreen"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this site

https://github.com/thevarungupta1/Android-Training-2/blob/master/SplashScreen/app/build.gradle

and

you seem forgot

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
```